# Java I have a String variable "a>b && z>c && x==y" and I want to convert into a normal if conditional expression

Tags: java, string, if-statement

```
int a=0;int z=0;int c=0;int x=0;int y=0; any more

String myarray[0] = "a>b && z>c && x==y";
String myarray[1] = "a<b && z<c && x==y";
String myarray[2] = "a>b && z>c && x<=y";
String myarray[n]

for(i=0;i<myarray.size();i++){
        if(myarray[i]){
        here code..
        }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* execute expressions written in a `String` like this in Java, and pick up the context of the surrounding program -- the value of `a`, etcetera.  You can evaluate self-contained expressions with the Javascript engine, but that doesn't solve your actual problem.

What you *could* do is make this a `boolean` array:

```
boolean[] myarray = new boolean[4];
myarray[0] = a>b && z>c && x==y;
myarray[1] = a<b && z<c && x==y;
myarray[2] = a>b && z>c && x<=y;
...
for(int i=0;i<myarray.length;i++){
    if(myarray[i]){
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will evaluate each expression once and only once. ie, if the value of `a` changes, those changes will not be reflected in `myarray`

Comment: myarray[i]=false ?? not run a>b && z>c && x==y or a<b && z<c && x==y

Comment: @cihad7887, what?  This approach sets `myarray[i]` to whether that expression _comes out_ true or false, not the expression itself, which there's no way to do and then evaluate it.

Comment: sorry i dont understand my mistake. i create List<Boolean> myarray=new ArrayList<Boolean>(); after   myarray.add(rs.getBoolean("column"));   after  myarray.get(0)-->false myarray.get(1)--> false ?? how to convert condition for if?

Comment: ...yes?  And then what happens?

Comment: i can send all my code? my question only example

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get out an expression, as a `String`, that refers to local variables in your program, and then evaluate it.  _You can't do that in Java._  You _could_ design a whole system to parse and evaluate Boolean expressions and explicitly pass in your variables, but that would be highly complex and well beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @cihad7887, learn how to write a parser for expressions like you're operating on (a compiler book might help), and then work out how to execute them.  There is not an easy solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Java, just gotta do a little boilerplate work.

```
public interface Expression {
    boolean evaluate();
}

public class Expression1 implements Expression {
    Integer a;
    Integer b;
    Integer c;
    Integer x;
    Integer y;
    Integer z;

    public Expression1(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c, Integer x, Integer y, Integer z){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        // ... the rest
    }

    public boolean evaluate(){
        return a>b && z>c && x==y;
    }
}

// the other Expression# classes

Expression[] expressions = new Expression[4];
expressions[0] = new Expression1(a,b,c,x,y,z);
expressions[1] = new Expression2(a,b,c,x,y,z);// make Expression2/Expression3/Expression4 classes

for(Expression expression : expressions){
    if(expression.evaluate()){
    // your code here
    }
}
```